Odoo 17 change PDF report name on wizard
I'm using Odoo 17 and I added a custom button on the project form view that displays wizard view to recap some informations and then export them inside a PDF report. Everything works fine except one thing : I can't change the name of the PDF. Here is my code :
report/ir_actions_report.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
   <record id="action_report_custom" model="ir.actions.report">
       <field name="name">My Custom PDF</field>
       <field name="model">report.custom_module.my_report</field>
       <field name="report_type">qweb-pdf</field>
       <field name="report_name">custom_module.my_report</field>
       <field name="report_file">custom_module.my_report</field>
       <field name="print_report_name">'the name of the file'</field>
       <field name="binding_type">report</field>
   </record>
</odoo>

report/custom_report.py
from odoo import api, models

class CustomReport(models.AbstractModel):
   _name = 'report.custom_module.my_report'
   description = 'desc'
   @api.model
   def _get_report_values(self, data=None):
        return {
              'docs': data,
              'doc_model':'project.pdf.report',
              'data': data['context']['x'],
        }
          

wizard/button.xml
<odoo>
    <record id="projet_edit_view_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name='name'>projet.edit.form.view</field>
        <field name='model'>project.pdf.report</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form>
                <field name="report_field" widget="edit_report"/>
                <footer>
                    <button name="print_report" type="object" string="Export PDF" class="btn btn-primary"/>
                </footer>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
</odoo>

wizard/button.py
from odoo import fields, models, api, _
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
import copy

class CustomGenerate (models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'project.pdf.report'
    _description='Génératino du PV '
    
    pv= fields.Char()
    
    # Export PDF  
    def print_report(self):
         #All the logic
         return self.env.ref('custom_module.action_report_custom').report_action(self, data=data)  
      

When I don't generate the report through the native print button instead, in the project model, the field  <field name="print_report_name"> works fine. But through a custom button, it doesn't, it keeps using the field  <field name="name">.
Any idea about how to change report file name through wizard?
Thanks a lot

Could you add the relevant part of your custom button's function on project.project?

Yes, I did it, just add the two files in the wizard
